# Time lapse of solar eclipse?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, timelapse, time, eclipse

I was thinking of taking a time lapse of the eclipse with my nikon d3300 but not of just the sun but of the sun and the landscape.
Unfortunately, I have to work during the eclipse and I was thinking of leaving the camera at home taking the pictures.
Do you have any tips on how to configure it? In terms of mode (auto vs manual), F values, ISO and so on..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mr. Eclipse is the resource for eclipses... photography and scientific, solar and lunar.  You are looking for an answer based on [How to Photograph a Solar Eclipse](http://www.mreclipse.com/SEphoto/SEphoto.html)

Comment: I've seen several people mention (in other posts) that they have their camera hooked up to their computer and then the computer takes the pictures. Perhaps you can do that and run a script or VNC to actually fire the shots.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same idea but I'm lucky enough to take day off.

I made some tests last Sunday and I will make a few adjustments Friday, but after gathering some more info on the net I will probably  go for

• Manual focus and manual settings
• F between 7.1 and 9
• Speed 1/8000 or 1/6400
• Aperture 16mm (full format)
• ISO 200

I'm interested in the landscape  but I don't want the the sun to be too over-exposed otherwise the Moon will barely be visible, so in my tests the landscape is dark but it's OK with me. Also, I live in Switzerland and the eclipse will only be at 70%.

Hope this helps

H